# How to cast string dataype to date in spark sql join condition: to_date not working and cast is throwing error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I'm   joining  two tables in redshift  using pyspark. The join condition is between date in one table with date in string format and of datatype varchar in other table

sales:

```
Sales    id    tx_date
123.5    1234  2019-02-15
154      1235  2019-02-14
```

datainfo :

```
Date      Multiplier 
02/15/19  2
02/14/19  3
```

And my spark sql is

```
data = spark.sql(""" select s.sales,s.id, ,d.multiplier from  sales s inner join
                    dateinfo d on s.tx_date=to_date(d.date,'mm/dd/yy')""")
```

this returns empty values for multiplier column

```
Sales    id    multiplier
123.5    1234  
154      1235
```

I've tried to cast the date

```
data = spark.sql(""" select s.sales,s.id, ,d.multiplier from  sales s inner join
                        dateinfo d on s.tx_date=to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(d.date,'mm/dd/yy')))"""
```

This throws error
AnalysisException: u'Invalid number of arguments for function cast;

How should i go about using date conversion in spark-sql

Answer (score 0):

you use the method cast incorrectly , you try this :

```
data = spark.sql(""" select s.sales,s.id, ,d.multiplier from  sales s inner join
                    dateinfo d on s.tx_date=to_date(cast(unix_timestamp(d.date,'mm/dd/yy') as TIMESTAMP))"""
```

Comment: i have already tried this, but the multiplier column is still empty